# DllImport Event Arguments Marshalling for Function in C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I'm really new to using DllImport and marshalling. I've read documentation from Microsoft and got most of what I need through trial and error but am having difficulties with a large function. I'm not even sure where to begin.

This is the C header:

```
extern EXPORT int kt10_library_init(void);
extern EXPORT int kt10_list_usb_devices(kt10_conn_string_t *list, int max_devices, int *dev_count);
extern EXPORT int kt10_connect(kt10_conn_string_t conn_string, int *id_conn, int timeout,
                        int (*event_connected)(int,char *,void *),
                        int (*event_connection_error)(int, char *,void *),
                        int (*event_disconnected)(int,char *,void *),
                        int (*event_live_data)(int,char *,int,int,float,float,void *),
                        void *user_data);
```

This is my code that works so far in C#

```
[DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_library_init();
[DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_list_usb_devices([In,Out] char[] list, int max_devices, ref UInt32 dev_count);
[DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_connect(char[] conn_string, ref UInt32 id_conn, int timeout,...
```

But I'm stumped with the **(Event)** stuff in the **k10_connect** function. Does someone have some sort of documentation they can point me to or guide me through on how I should write that? I'm not even sure what I should be searching for. I don't have much to go on besides the header.

Here's some documentation I was reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0

**Update 1**
Okay, based on the comments I'm creating delegates for those arguments which is giving me a starting point, but I'm getting memory access violations. Unfortunately I do not have access to any documentation. This library was not intended to be open source.

```
[DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_connect(
        char[] conn_string, 
        ref UInt32 id_conn, 
        int timeout, 
        ref event_connected onConnected,
        ref event_connection_error onConnectionError,
        ref event_disconnected onDisconnected,
        ref event_live_data onLiveData,
        ref unknown onUserData);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int event_connected(int id,ref char conChar,ref unknown fun);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int event_connection_error(int id,ref char conChar,ref unknown fun);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int event_disconnected(int id,ref char conChar,ref unknown fun);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate int event_live_data(int id, ref char conChar, int num1, int num2, float num3, float num4, ref unknown fun);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void unknown();

public static void Connect(string device)
{
    UInt32 connId = 0;
    var Unknown = new unknown(OnUnknown);
    var connectedEvent = new event_connected(Event);
    var connectionErrorEvent = new event_connection_error(Event);
    var disconnectedEvent = new event_disconnected(Event);
    var liveDataEvent = new event_live_data(EventLiveData);
    kt10_connect(device.ToCharArray(), ref connId, 1000, ref connectedEvent, ref connectionErrorEvent, ref disconnectedEvent, ref liveDataEvent, ref Unknown);
    Debug.WriteLine("Attempting connection");
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909583/using-delegates-in-c-sharp-as-callback-for-c-dllimported-functions) for inspiration.

Comment: Without knowing what those pointers are supposed to represent, we can't begin to help you. Do you have any documentation? The function pointers will become delegates, but it's not clear what the pointers such as `*id_conn` are supposed to be

Comment: Those are function pointers, in C# you need to declare a delegate that has the same signature.  With the attribute [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)].  Make sure that the delegate objects you pass cannot be garbage-collected, store them in static variables.

Comment: The method declarations also need work.  Delegates are reference types, delete `ref` from the declaration.  char* in C is most typically `string` in C#.  Favor `IntPtr` for void*.  First parameter of kt10_connect() is unlikely to be correct, but hard to guess what kt10_conn_string_t might mean.   Try string.  You ignored the advice to store the delegate objects in a static variable, that was a bad idea.  Do talk to whomever provided you with this DLL and .h file, this kind of guessing is not productive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone in the comments for the help on delegates. That's exactly what I needed to get the function to work. I was able to get the connection id back and use it to get the serial number of the device!

I probably have more work to do, but that is mainly what I needed to get the program to work.

```
private const int KT10V2_MAX_CONNECTION_STR_LEN = 128;
    //private char[] 
    [DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_library_init();
    [DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_list_usb_devices([In,Out] char[] list, int max_devices, ref UInt32 dev_count);
    [DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_get_serial(uint connectionID, [In, Out] char[] serialNumber);
    [DllImport("libkt10int.dll")] private static extern int kt10_connect(
        char[] conn_string, 
        ref UInt32 id_conn, 
        int timeout, 
        event_connected onConnected,
        event_connection_error onConnectionError,
        event_disconnected onDisconnected,
        event_live_data onLiveData,
        unknown onUserData);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate int event_connected(int id,ref char conChar, unknown fun);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate int event_connection_error(int id,ref char conChar, unknown fun);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate int event_disconnected(int id,ref char conChar, unknown fun);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate int event_live_data(int id, ref char conChar, int num1, int num2, float num3, float num4, unknown fun);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void unknown();

    static readonly unknown Unknown = new(OnUnknown);
    static readonly event_connected connectedEvent = new(Event);
    static readonly event_connection_error connectionErrorEvent = new(Event);
    static readonly event_disconnected disconnectedEvent = new(Event);
    static readonly event_live_data liveDataEvent = new(EventLiveData);
    public static uint Connect(string device)
    {
        UInt32 connId = 0;
        kt10_connect(device.ToCharArray(), ref connId, 1000, connectedEvent,  connectionErrorEvent, disconnectedEvent, liveDataEvent, Unknown);
        return connId;
    }
    public static string GetSerial(uint connectionID)
    {
        var serialNumber = new char[KT10V2_MAX_CONNECTION_STR_LEN];
        kt10_get_serial(connectionID, serialNumber);
        return new string(serialNumber);
    }
    public static void InitKTLibrary()
    {
        kt10_library_init();
    }

    public static string[] ListUSBDevices(int maxDevices = 99)
    {
        UInt32 devCount = 0;
        var list = new char[KT10V2_MAX_CONNECTION_STR_LEN];
        kt10_list_usb_devices(list, maxDevices, ref devCount);
        var resultString = new string(list);
        resultString = resultString.Trim();
        if (devCount == 0)
            return Array.Empty<string>();
        return resultString.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private static void OnUnknown()
    {
    
    }


    private static int Event(int id, ref char conChar, unknown fun)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    private static int EventLiveData(int id, ref char conChar, int num1, int num2, float num3, float num4, unknown fun)
    {
        return -1;
    }
```